# (Re) exporting boost::system::generic_category() in boost 1.7x boost_system library?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-libraries, abi, dllexport

I'm butting my head against a *runtime* issue. After upgrading to boost 1.71.0 certain existing binaries fail to load because the `boost::system::generic_category()` function is apparently no longer exported from libboost_system. This must have changed in a boost version after 1.66 .

I could work around that on Linux by keeping my older runtimes libraries (libboost_system-mt.so.1.59.0 in my case). Clumsy but common.
No such luck on Mac, however; there boost builds without the usual platform shared library versioning.

It seems strange that a basic, behind-the-scenes function would be removed from the ABI; I have yet to find a document that states one indeed has to rebuild all dependents when upgrading boost to 1.7x (or whatever version broke ABI). Googling the issue seems to give (lots of) hits only on build-time link failures.

I've asked on the boost build system ML about ABI breakage and building versioned dylibs, but I'm trying my luck here for a complementary approach.

Is it possible (and if so, how) to get this function back among the exported functions in libboost_system-mt? AFAICT it is being called indirectly through other boost APIs that my failing executables do use, so it may be tricky to export the function. The code in question is a bit too obfuscated for me to just start hacking around in without at least having a proper "intellisense" support in an IDE.

Comment: boost provides no ABI guarantees, mixing versions isn't supported

Comment: Does OS X have a mechanism to override the loaded dylibs? For example, in Windows, you can just put your DLLs in the executable directory and since the loader searches there first, your preferred DLLs get loaded instead of the system ones (barring WinSxS nonsense.) This of course assumes that you want to upgrade your system libraries but can get away with holding your local libs back at the version that did work.

Comment: My question clearly indicates what I'm interested in, and that's not in mixing versions in a single running application. And, no, OS X has always been very strict about the libraries it pulls in, using a combination of hardcoded absolute, *resolved* paths that must match how the library announces itself, and version info encoded in the binary itself. Overriding that would require messing with the environment for only that apps that need it. Too cumbersome if other solutions exist.